# CakePHP redirectng

Tags: cakephp

I have 2 view files, lets say `file1.ctp` and `file2.ctp`. What I want, when I am successfully done doing something in `file1.ctp`, it'll show me a "Successful" message and redirect me to `file2.ctp`. It should be automatic.

Comment: You can use client-side redirects on your "successfully done" view. Either "meta redirect" or javascript redirect.  The "meta" is simpler because you can set a delay in seconds. Otherwise, there are lots of JS redirect scripts if you google for them.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion. Can you give me an example of code snippet ? I want to use "meta redirect".@Costa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Controller::flash

From [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19572631/cakephp-redirectng#comment29051051_19572962), what you're describing is [`Controller::flash`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers.html#Controller::flash):

```
Controller::flash($message, $url, $pause, $layout)
```

> Like redirect(), the flash() method is used to direct a user to a new page after an operation. The flash() method is different in that it shows a message before passing the user on to another URL.

#### Example usage

Consider 2 controller actions, like so:

```
function step1() {
    ...
    $this->flash('Step1 complete, now starting step2', array('action' => 'step2'))
}

function step2() {
    ...
}
```

which when accessed at `/example/step1` would execute the controller action, then show a plain page with the text `Step1 complete, now starting step2`, pause for 1 second (the default) and then send the user to `/example/step2` using a [meta refresh](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/H76.html).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the render function in CakePHP. Like This:

```
$this->render('file2');
```

You should use this in your Controller.

Comment: Yeah, I know it. My problem is, I want to show a message, like "Successfully done, now loading file2 page", and then redirect the user to "file2.ctp". User doesn't have to do anything.@C Travel